# must declare a body because it is not marked abstract extern or partial

Tags: c#

I have the code and getting the error shown above. But the Class is defined as abstract, so I shouldn't need a code body.

```
public abstract class Endian
    {
        public short ToInt16(byte[] value, int startIndex)
        {
            return unchecked((short)FromBytes(value, startIndex, 2));
        }

        public int ToInt32(byte[] value, int startIndex)
        {
            return unchecked((int)FromBytes(value, startIndex, 4));
        }

        public long ToInt64(byte[] value, int startIndex)
        {
            return FromBytes(value, startIndex, 8);
        }

        // This same method can be used by int16, int32 and int64.
        protected virtual long FromBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len); // << Error here
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `virtual` modifier is used to indicate that the method *can* be overridden in a derived class but needs to be defined in the base class (i.e. by giving it a method body).  You want to use the `abstract` modifier instead of `virtual`, as the error message indicates, which means that the method *must* be overridden.

Methods that are abstract must have the `abstract` modifier even though the class is already marked `abstract` in order to clearly differentiate them, and they cannot contain a method body (just a semicolon at the end).  It's just the rule and it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

To be abstract, a method must be declared as such:

```
protected abstract long FromBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len);
```

You where declaring it virtual, which means it is a proper method, with an implementation, that can be overridden by derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

> But the Class is defined as abstract, so I shouldn't need a code body.

Why would you expect that?

`protected virtual long FromBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len);`

Method is still marked as virtual, it expects a body and can be overriden. You should declare it as abstract if you don't want to add the definition.